# Data loss when calling a HTTP request with huge response body in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, okhttp, resttemplate

I have a Spring boot app that reads a S3 presigned URL that contains a huge amount of data in JSON format.
When I directly fetch the data using POSTMAN I can see the content length is around 102MB but in the application it is 22.27 MB.

I tried with both RestTemplate and OkHttp. Both give the same results.

When Calling S3 URL directly:
[image]

When Calling via RestTemplate and OkHttp:
[image]

This is my sample code with RestTemplate.

```
ResponseEntity<List<Product>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
            new URI(fileUrl),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Product>>() {}
    );

    if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Why this is happening so? How can I get the whole data amount contains in the S3 URL?

Comment: You are creating `Product` instances, doe they map all the information? Also if you are only proxying the content, why read it fully, create objects and recreate the json. Just pass it through as is instead of the intermediate step. It is faster and uses less memory.

Comment: No. They do not map all information. Some data are missing. How can I create objects to recreate the json.?  @M.Deinum

Comment: Again why would you map if you only proxy.. Just pass the JSON as is as that is what you need to do.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I have used OkHttpClient as well. So it returns response body as a String. When I check this String it has all the data. Where the data loss is when  I convert String to Java object class using object mapper.  Why is that and any solution for this? @M.Deinum

Comment: The solution is, as mentioned twice before, don't convert to objects. Apparently you don't need the conversion and you should be just passing along the raw data. If you don't map everything in your product what should happen with the unmapped data, how shold that automagically appear in the respoinse? If you need the data as is, then just read the String (or even better an inputstream) and copy that directly to the client. It is faster, uses less memory.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. But the problem is I need to persist these data into the database. That is why I am trying to convert it to object to persist the data easily. @M.Deinum

Comment: Which is something you left conveniently out of the question and is mentioned nowhere. If you map to objects and don't map all the fields you will obviously get a different result. Also is the json you receive initially formatted, if so it will have more content due to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is an older HttpClient based on `HttpURLConnection`. May be you can try this and check the content length that you see from it. Although, since you got the same problematic response content length from 2 different clients doesn't bode well for my idea, but still. `HttpClient` I am talking about comes with Open Source MgntUtils java library written and maintained by me. Here is [HttpClient Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library can be obtained from [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)